# How can I list all the unique values under max cardinality to an email alert

Tags: elasticsearch, elastalert, elastalert2

```
name: Recon-Same Source IP Scanning Multiple IPs
index: "*:so-*"
type: cardinality
cardinality_field: "destination.ip"
max_cardinality: 15
timeframe:
  minutes: 5
filter:
- query_string:
    query: "event.module:panw AND source.ip:*"
query_key: source.ip    
alert:
- "email"
```

Is there a way for me to extract the unique list of destination.ip that triggered this rule and show it on my email alert ?

I tried this on my email part of the config.

```
email: 
 - "admin1@test.com.ph"
 - "admin2@test.com.ph"

from_addr: "emaildummy@test.com.ph"

###########################
email_format: "html"
###########################
alert_text_type: alert_text_only
alert_text_args: [source.ip, "@timestamp", destination.ip, max_cardinality_result, count]
alert_text: |
        The following source IP has scanned multiple destination IPs:
    
        Source IP: {{ctx.results.0.query_key}}
    
        Unique Destination IPs:
        {{#ctx.results.0.aggregations.unique_ips.buckets}}
          - {{key}}
        {{/ctx.results.0.aggregations.unique_ips.buckets}}
        <p>Source IP: {2}</p>
        <p>Destination IP count {4}{{destination.ip}}{{ports}}</p>
```

Comment: I don't know much about the tool you're using (elastalert), but if it uses Cardinality Aggregation by Elastic under the hood (which it likely is) - no, there's no way to get the _concrete_ values of that field. As this aggregation yields only approximate count of distinct values (in the scope of your query).